BLAST+ error when running against a custom database: mdb_env_open: The system cannot find the path specified
I am currently attempting to run BLAST+ against a custom database using the following command:
>\MATLAB\blast_plus\bin\blastn.exe -db genotype.fas -query C:\Users\jzl2\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tp2cdfa15f_9c682_4858_a298_6b0fd37d7674 -out C:\Users\jzl2\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tp7dfbbcd2_b0df_4206_a36a_d2517d67fcff

However, when running this command, I am getting the following error message:
Error: mdb_env_open: The system cannot find the path specified.

Any guidance as to what exactly this error means, the file it is referring to and how to go about a resolution would be much appreciated. In case it would be helpful to know, I am using an older version of Blast (v 2.11.0), but this has not been an issue until very recently.

Please show where the database you're trying to use can be found. genotype.fas is an unusual name.

Hello. Thanks for the reply. I was actually able to fix this error by running make blast db. Turns out the database was corrupted and needed to be remade.

Can you please add this as an answer? It will help other people encountering the same thing in the future.

I was able to solve this issue using the make blast db command in order to re create what was seemingly a corrupted database file. Hope this helps anyone who encounters a similar issue.

Please elaborate on the command which failed and how you corrected it. Edit your question instead of commenting on it.
